# Jquery Flot - Initialize to specific canvas location

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flot

I am trying to figure out a way to specify the specific location on the canvas to center on when the chart initializes.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do that?

I thought perhaps it might be possible to trigger a plotpan to that position, but I can't seem to get it working.  Has anyone ever tried to do this before?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this, I found a very smart solution here: [How to save (preserve) the zoom state of flot graphs on Update with AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814906/how-to-save-preserve-the-zoom-state-of-flot-graphs-on-update-with-ajax)

Basically, the Flot plot has a function `var options = plot.getOptions();`

Then before you plot, just do that and it will basically clone the chart's positioning and whatnot to the new one.

```
$.plot(
    // selector
    $chart,
    // line data
    data,
    // plot configs
    options);
```

Boom, it even preserves if you have any lines that are toggled on or off.